# Can Firebase send and receive in the background on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, firebase, background-process

My Objective C app on iOS 7 gets location updates in the background from either the startUpdatingsignificantLocationChanges or startUpdatingLocation delegate (which one depends on the mode that the app is in, but I don't think it matters).

In the delegate, I gather the location info, write it to a dictionary, and then write the dictionary to a Firebase.

```
// this code is in the location update delegate routine

// the code that gathers the various elements that go into the dictionary
// are omitted for clarity, I don't think that they matter

// we may be running in the background on iOS 7 when we are called!

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newLocation.coordinate.latitude] stringValue], @"Latitude",
   [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newLocation.coordinate.longitude] stringValue], @"Longitude",
   [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newLocation.horizontalAccuracy] stringValue], @"Accuracy",
   formattedDateString, @"TimeNow",
   [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp], @"TimeStamp",
   [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:interval] stringValue], @"Date",
   self.mode, @"Mode",
   nil];

   // Write it once to CurrentLocation
   [ref setValue:dictionary];

   // yes, I know this is clumsy
   fbTmp = [NSMutableString stringWithString: fbRoot];
   [fbTmp appendString : @"/locationHistory"];
   ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:fbTmp]; 

   // Now write it again to the locationHistory list
   ref = [ref childByAutoId];
   [ref setValue:dictionary];
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (i.e. in the same run of the app, sometimes the location gets written to the Firebase successfully as expected, and sometimes it doesn't.  There isn't any obvious rhyme or reason to when it seems to work and when it doesn't).

I suspect that the issue is that the Firebase write is not completing successfully in background mode, but I'm not sure.  I am very new to iOS and Objective C and Firebase.

My app is marked in its Capabilities as requiring background services for Location updates and Background fetch (the latter my random attempt to fix this problem, the former I know that I need).

My suspicion is that I need to tell the OS that I need time to complete the write with a backkgroundTask, and then terminate the background task in the completion block of the firebase write - has anyone verified that that will work when running in background mode?

If so, do I just need to do that in the second write (assuming that they are completed in order), or in both (with a counter that I count down as each write completes)?

Any hints most appreciated.

Comment: What apps can do in the background is the purview of the OS, not of Firebase. It stays connected for some arbitrary length, and then the OS severs the socket connection as it pleases. That probably accounts for the "works sometimes".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to finish your task in background. It says so in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1):

> If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a little extra time to complete that task, it can call the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: or beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of the UIApplication object to request some additional execution time. Calling either of these methods delays the suspension of your app temporarily, giving it a little extra time to finish its work. Upon completion of that work, your app must call the endBackgroundTask: method to let the system know that it is finished and can be suspended.

Just put your code in a background task, give it maximum time (3 minutes I think).

Read up on [Apple app lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) and everything should clear up for you for future reference.